# How to wrap a string containing a character with a tag?

Tags: linux, awk, sed, tags, video-subtitles

Hi I'm a Linux noob and I'd to know how to replace a line starting with "/" with  tag.
Here's an example:

```
/Foo is awesome
```

and I would like to get

```
<i>Foo is awesome</i>
```

I would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use awk with `substr` like this:

```
awk '/^\//{$0 = "<i>" substr($0,2) "</i>"}1' file
```

When there is a `/` at the start of the line, append the tags and use `substr` to remove the slash from the original line. `1` is `true` so awk does the default action for each line, which is to print the line.

Comment: Works beautifully. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
sed '\#^/# {s//<i>/;s#$#</i>#;}' YourFile
# or (with maybe space before)
sed '\#^ */# {s//<i>/;s#$#</i>#;}' YourFile
```

another sed way, this allow to work on this line (if something else to do and not simply sourround by tag)

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below sed command,

```
$ sed 's~^/\(.*\)~<i>\1</i>~' file
<i>Foo is awesome</i>
```

Through awk,

```
$ awk '/^\//{sub(/^\//,"<i>");sub(/$/,"</i>")}1' file
<i>Foo is awesome</i>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk 'sub("^/","<i>"){$0 = $0 "</i>"} 1' file
<i>Foo is awesome</i>
```

Comment: So the return value of `sub` indicates whether the pattern was matched?

Comment: Yes. The return value of sub() and gsub() is how may times the regexp was matched and in the case of sub() that can only be 1 or 0.